# JSF 1.2 migration issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf-1.2

I am facing a issue while migrating JSF 1.1.12 to 1.2. 
I am having a JSP page which has JSP and JSF components (A.jsp). This page is included in another JSP (B.jsp) with a custom tag.

The issue is that when I migrated from JSF 1.1 to JSF 1.2 all the JSF tags present in A.jsp are written able my JSP tags present in B.jsp.

JSP tags present in A.jsp are written inside B.jsp at the correct location but not JSF tags.

I know there are changes in JSF 1.2 in the way it handles JSP and JSF tag. But I am not able to identify the exact problem.

Any help will be great

I just check javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport.getBodyContent() returns only JSP components and not JSF component with JSF 1.2. In JSF 1.1 it used to return all the JSP and JSF components